# Table footnotes not showing

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have a really large table (that i have splitted in three lines) with footnotes. When I typeset it (TeXworks), the table loads fine, while the footnotes are not showing. The labels are showing though.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\lrbox0}c<{\endlrbox}@{}}
%the H columns will now be hidden

\begin{document}

\begin{table}%[p]
  \textbf{\caption{Št. kolonij v odvisnosti od datuma}}
  \begin{tabular}{||l||r|r|r|r|r|rHHHHHHHH|}
    \hline \hline
    Datum & 9.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 11.\,2.\,2017 & 12.\,2.\,2017 & 13.\,2.\,2017 & 14.\,2.\,2017 & 15.\,2.\,2017 & 16.\,2.\,2017 & 17.\,2.\,2017 & 18.\,2.\,2017 & 19.\,2.\,2017 & 20.\,2.\,2017 & 21.\,2.\,2017 \\ \hline
    Ura & 17.51 & 6.48  & 18.10 & 17.34 & 17.24 & 17.57 & 20.14 & 17.23 & 18.10 & 18.22 & 18.02 & 16.56 & 21.29 & 19.05 \\ \hline \hline
    SD \footnote{FN1} & 18 & 19 & 17 & 23 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 25 & 28 & 38 & 39 & 38 & 37 & 37 \\ \hline
    MT \footnote{FN2} & 32 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 34 & 39 & 43 & 42 & 41 & 45 & 48 & 47 & 47 & 48 \\ \hline
    RT \footnote{FN3} & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 8 \\ \hline
    ŽR \footnote{FN4} & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 10 & 10 & 11 & 11 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    KV \footnote{FN5} & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    BA \footnote{FN6} & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
    KO \footnote{FN7} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \vspace{0.3cm} %i want to create space here, this vspace creates it below this part.
  \begin{tabular}{|HHHHHHHr|r|r|r|r|rHH|}
    \hline \hline
    Datum & 9.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 11.\,2.\,2017 & 12.\,2.\,2017 & 13.\,2.\,2017 & 14.\,2.\,2017 & 15.\,2.\,2017 & 16.\,2.\,2017 & 17.\,2.\,2017 & 18.\,2.\,2017 & 19.\,2.\,2017 & 20.\,2.\,2017 & 21.\,2.\,2017 \\ \hline
    Ura & 17.51 & 6.48  & 18.10 & 17.34 & 17.24 & 17.57 & 20.14 & 17.23 & 18.10 & 18.22 & 18.02 & 16.56 & 21.29 & 19.05 \\ \hline \hline
    SD & 18 & 19 & 17 & 23 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 25 & 28 & 38 & 39 & 38 & 37 & 37 \\ \hline
    MT & 32 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 34 & 39 & 43 & 42 & 41 & 45 & 48 & 47 & 47 & 48 \\ \hline
    RT & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 8 \\ \hline
    ŽR & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 10 & 10 & 11 & 11 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    KV & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    BA & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
    KO & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline     \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{|HHHHHHHHHHHHHr|r||}
    \hline \hline
    Datum & 9.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 11.\,2.\,2017 & 12.\,2.\,2017 & 13.\,2.\,2017 & 14.\,2.\,2017 & 15.\,2.\,2017 & 16.\,2.\,2017 & 17.\,2.\,2017 & 18.\,2.\,2017 & 19.\,2.\,2017 & 20.\,2.\,2017 & 21.\,2.\,2017 \\ \hline
    Ura & 17.51 & 6.48  & 18.10 & 17.34 & 17.24 & 17.57 & 20.14 & 17.23 & 18.10 & 18.22 & 18.02 & 16.56 & 21.29 & 19.05 \\ \hline \hline
    SD & 18 & 19 & 17 & 23 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 25 & 28 & 38 & 39 & 38 & 37 & 37 \\ \hline
    MT & 32 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 34 & 39 & 43 & 42 & 41 & 45 & 48 & 47 & 47 & 48 \\ \hline
    RT & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 8 \\ \hline
    ŽR & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 10 & 10 & 11 & 11 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    KV & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    BA & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
    KO & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have also tried `\clearpage` but it is not working either. And also, I want to create space between first and second "row" of tables (first and second table), where the comment is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the footnotes to print, you need to encase the *contents* of the `table` environment (not the `table` environment itself...) in a `minipage` of width `\textwidth`.

By default, the footnote "numbers" will be printed as italic lowercase alphabetic letters (a, b, ...). If you want arabic numerals instead, just issue the instruction

```
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
```

immediately ahead of `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=bf,skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\lrbox0}c<{\endlrbox}@{}} % H columns will be hidden

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % <--- new
\caption{Št. kolonij v odvisnosti od datuma}
  \begin{tabular}{||l||r|r|r|r|r|rHHHHHHHH|}
    \hline \hline
    Datum & 9.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 11.\,2.\,2017 & 12.\,2.\,2017 & 13.\,2.\,2017 & 14.\,2.\,2017 & 15.\,2.\,2017 & 16.\,2.\,2017 & 17.\,2.\,2017 & 18.\,2.\,2017 & 19.\,2.\,2017 & 20.\,2.\,2017 & 21.\,2.\,2017 \\ \hline
    Ura & 17.51 & 6.48  & 18.10 & 17.34 & 17.24 & 17.57 & 20.14 & 17.23 & 18.10 & 18.22 & 18.02 & 16.56 & 21.29 & 19.05 \\ \hline \hline
    SD \footnote{FN1} & 18 & 19 & 17 & 23 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 25 & 28 & 38 & 39 & 38 & 37 & 37 \\ \hline
    MT \footnote{FN2} & 32 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 34 & 39 & 43 & 42 & 41 & 45 & 48 & 47 & 47 & 48 \\ \hline
    RT \footnote{FN3} & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 8 \\ \hline
    ŽR \footnote{FN4} & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 10 & 10 & 11 & 11 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    KV \footnote{FN5} & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    BA \footnote{FN6} & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
    KO \footnote{FN7} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{0.3cm} % leave some blank lines above/below this instruction

  \begin{tabular}{|HHHHHHHr|r|r|r|r|rHH|}
    \hline \hline
    Datum & 9.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 11.\,2.\,2017 & 12.\,2.\,2017 & 13.\,2.\,2017 & 14.\,2.\,2017 & 15.\,2.\,2017 & 16.\,2.\,2017 & 17.\,2.\,2017 & 18.\,2.\,2017 & 19.\,2.\,2017 & 20.\,2.\,2017 & 21.\,2.\,2017 \\ \hline
    Ura & 17.51 & 6.48  & 18.10 & 17.34 & 17.24 & 17.57 & 20.14 & 17.23 & 18.10 & 18.22 & 18.02 & 16.56 & 21.29 & 19.05 \\ \hline \hline
    SD & 18 & 19 & 17 & 23 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 25 & 28 & 38 & 39 & 38 & 37 & 37 \\ \hline
    MT & 32 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 34 & 39 & 43 & 42 & 41 & 45 & 48 & 47 & 47 & 48 \\ \hline
    RT & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 8 \\ \hline
    ŽR & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 10 & 10 & 11 & 11 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    KV & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    BA & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
    KO & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline     \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{0.3cm} % leave some blank lines above/below this instruction

  \begin{tabular}{|HHHHHHHHHHHHHr|r||}
    \hline \hline
    Datum & 9.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 10.\,2.\,2017 & 11.\,2.\,2017 & 12.\,2.\,2017 & 13.\,2.\,2017 & 14.\,2.\,2017 & 15.\,2.\,2017 & 16.\,2.\,2017 & 17.\,2.\,2017 & 18.\,2.\,2017 & 19.\,2.\,2017 & 20.\,2.\,2017 & 21.\,2.\,2017 \\ \hline
    Ura & 17.51 & 6.48  & 18.10 & 17.34 & 17.24 & 17.57 & 20.14 & 17.23 & 18.10 & 18.22 & 18.02 & 16.56 & 21.29 & 19.05 \\ \hline \hline
    SD & 18 & 19 & 17 & 23 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 25 & 28 & 38 & 39 & 38 & 37 & 37 \\ \hline
    MT & 32 & 35 & 35 & 35 & 34 & 39 & 43 & 42 & 41 & 45 & 48 & 47 & 47 & 48 \\ \hline
    RT & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 9 & 8 \\ \hline
    ŽR & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 10 & 10 & 11 & 11 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    KV & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    BA & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
    KO & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, however, it throws me this error:
`! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.228     \textbf
                 {\caption{Št. kolonij v odvisnosti od datuma}}`

Comment: @RedstoneTehnik - Well, I do *not* get this error with the example shown above. My hunch is that you've placed the `table` environment inside the `minipage` environment, instead the other way around. Please re-read the code and instructions I gave.

Comment: Thanks, that was the exact problem. Now it works perfect!

Comment: I tried using the solution mentioned here. I still can't see the footnotes. I am using `tabularx` environment though. Something needs to be taken care of with that?

Comment: @elprofessor - I'm afraid you haven't given me nearly enough information to come up with a diagnosis of the situation, let alone determine a cure. May I ask you to post a new query?

Comment: @Mico I just created a MWE to post. I am able to see the footnotes there. However, it is not working with my actual thesis document where the table is typeset. I am trying to figure out why this is. Me posting the MWE will defeat the purpose as it works :) sigh!

Comment: @mico I posted a new query [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537358/footnote-not-typeset-in-sidewaystable-in-tabularx-env-when-hyperref-is-loaded)